# Some WorldGuard commands not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit, minecraft-worldguard

I'm making a map in Minecraft 1.7.10.

I'm trying to protect a specific area from getting destroyed by other players.

I'm using WorldEdit 1.7.10-6.0-beta-01 and WorldGuard 6.1, as well as 3 other mods (BuildFaster, TMI & SecurityCraft).

The program seems like it is working. I do `//copy` or `//paste`, and it is working without any issues. But it fails whenever I'm trying to protect my world area by doing the following steps:

1. Select first position. (Success)
2. Select second position. (Success)
3. `/expand vert` (Success)
4. `/define nameOfArea` (Failed)

I have tried lots of different commands to protect this area (like `/region claim Name`, etc.), but it still tells me the same message.

[image: a screenshot of successful commands, followed by a failed command]

`Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands`

Does anyone knows why it doesn't work? Do I have to download Bukkit or any other mods? Is the area too big to do this?

By the way, there are many different commands that are also not working well.
For example, `/set day` instead of `/set time day` isn't working, it shows me the same error on image as above.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
/region define <id>
```

Make sure to check the newest [WorldGuard documentation](http://docs.enginehub.org/manual/worldguard/latest/regions/quick-start/).
Also, as far as I know, CommandBook had commands like

```
/time day
```

I'm not sure if CommandBook still works with new version, though.

Comment: Yes i have try many commands just like this and /region claim etc. but nothing happen, it's still shows me the same message. I have the latest version on any mods on my folder.

Comment: On the command you said, what exactly i have to put on <id> ?

Comment: theoretically any name should be okay...

Comment: Do i need something more than world edit and world guard to do this ? Is it easy for you to send me direct links or something ? I've searched about it too much and nothing. Do i need Bukkit to do it? Have you ever done that im talking about? Do i miss something ? :